# How To Convert A Dataframe Column Into 2D Array?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, data-science

I've the below dataset:

[Sample Dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aXHzz.png)

My objective is to create a 2D array of the column 'Products' for this dataset.

Now, if I do the following code:

```
prodarr = Order_Details[['Product']].to_numpy()
```

It returns me the result as follows:

```
 [['PRODUCT_75'],
       ['PRODUCT_75'],
       ['PRODUCT_63'],
       ['PRODUCT_63'],
       ['PRODUCT_34,PRODUCT_86,PRODUCT_57,PRODUCT_89'],
       ['PRODUCT_34,PRODUCT_66,PRODUCT_58,PRODUCT_83'],
       ['PRODUCT_75'],
       ['PRODUCT_63,PRODUCT_90,PRODUCT_27,PRODUCT_5'],
       ['PRODUCT_26'],
       ['PRODUCT_63'],
       ['PRODUCT_63'],
       ['PRODUCT_5,PRODUCT_34'],
       ['PRODUCT_84,PRODUCT_27'],
       ['PRODUCT_27'], ...]
```

Now, this is an undesirable situation for me, as I wanted all the distinct products as different elements in a given row. What I mean is that the output should instead be like this:

```
[['PRODUCT_75'],['PRODUCT_63'],['PRODUCT_63'],['PRODUCT_34','PRODUCT_86','PRODUCT_57','PRODUCT_89'], ['PRODUCT_34','PRODUCT_66','PRODUCT_58','PRODUCT_83'], ['PRODUCT_75'], ['PRODUCT_63','PRODUCT_90','PRODUCT_27','PRODUCT_5'], ...]
```

This means that it is that on each row there are multiple columns of strings and not just one.

How should I approach this conundrum? Will have to segregate the strings based on commas and make use of **df.iterrows**?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Actually, both the arrays and their arrangement posted are the same. It's just the matter of display in the Python that causes the difference. Not a big problem

Comment: @KevinChoonLiangYew Thanks for the welcome. Actually, I'm doing a market-basket analysis for the above data and so I need the latter format of strings to work on properties like lift, confidence, etc., and establish a relationship of antecedents & consequents. I know I didn't give the context, since I thought it was irrelevant, but I really need the data format in the latter form.

Comment: Try this `print([list(i) for i in df.to_numpy()])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is one way to do it

```
df = df['product'].str.split(',', expand=True)
```

```
    0   1   2   3
0   PRODUCT_75  None    None    None
1   PRODUCT_75  None    None    None
2   PRODUCT_63  None    None    None
3   PRODUCT_63  None    None    None
4   PRODUCT_34  PRODUCT_86  PRODUCT_57  PRODUCT_89
5   PRODUCT_34  PRODUCT_66  PRODUCT_58  PRODUCT_83
6   PRODUCT_75  None    None    None
7   PRODUCT_63  PRODUCT_90  PRODUCT_27  PRODUCT_5
8   PRODUCT_26  None    None    None
9   PRODUCT_63  None    None    None
10  PRODUCT_63  None    None    None
11  PRODUCT_5   PRODUCT_34  None    None
12  PRODUCT_84  PRODUCT_27  None    None
13  PRODUCT_27  None    None    None
```

Comment: Even though this wasn't exactly I'd looked for, but this certainly did help me in figuring out on how to split it into dataframe which can consequently be easily regrouped into numpy array. Only one dilemma still exists, tho. How do I get rid of those 'None' values? I tried other fixes of dropna(), but strangely that eliminates all other rows from the dataframe which have at least one "None" in them.